# Prepositional phrases adverbial or adjective

Tags: prepositions

> To be capable of working with people of different cultures on a project without having any conflicts is the ability we must possess.

"Of different cultures" is an adjective describing "people"

and I think
"with people of different cultures" "on a project" "without having any conflicts" should be adverbs that modify "working" instead of adjective phrases that modify the noun in front of it?

"on a project" is not an adjective for "cultures"

"without having any conflicts" is not an adjective for" project"

Am I right about this?

If what I wrote is correct, then it seems like multiple adverbial prepositional phrases are used to modify the same verb , is this acceptable?

Comment: "Of different cultures" is a PP functioning as complement of "people". "With people of different cultures", "on a project" and "without having any conflicts" are PPs functioning as complement of "working". Some people would call the PPs modifiers, but I think they are actually complements.

Comment: @BillJ I'll buy the *with* and *on* PP as "complements"--their sense is determined by the verb--but the *without* PP seems to me to be a "modifier" or "adjunct".

Comment: @BillJ Is there anything missing from your comment that keeps it from being an answer?

Comment: There is no rule against multiple adverbs (or adverbial phrases) modifying the same verb (or adjective). Did someone tell you there was?

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the sentence a little, since it is not a good one, even if it is grammatical. That you can string phrases together like that does not mean that you should do so.

We will leave out **on projects** at first.

> To be capable of working without conflicts with people of different cultures is important.

Where do we put **on projects**?  At the end?

> To be capable of working without conflicts with people of different cultures is important on projects.

At the beginning?

> On projects, to be capable of working without conflicts with people of different cultures is important.

Should we reorder the constituents?

> On projects with people of different cultures, to be capable of working without conflicts is important.
>
> With people of different cultures on projects, it is important to be capable of working without conflicts.

Maybe we should use handy "it" and stick in a "when":

> It is important when working on projects with people of different cultures to be capable of working without conflicts.
>
> It is important to be capable of working without conflicts when on projects with people of different cultures.

Answer (score 0):

The original is quite awkwardly written. I would rephrase it as

> We must be capable of working on projects with people of different cultures, without having any conflicts.

It is certianly possible for multiple adverbs or adverbial phrases to modify a verb, but the original shows lack of focus.  The key concept is "working on a project" or "working on projects" and splitting this reduces clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes and yes.

It is completely "legal" to have multiple adverbs on the same verb. For example, "George worked quickly and accurately". Some or all of those adverbs can be adverbial phrases. It's perfectly reasonable to want to modify a verb in more than one way.

By the way, I think the sentence as given is a little awkward, but it's grammatically correct and not hard to understand. I think "to be capable of ... is the ability" is redundant. And it seems awkward to put "on a project", what you are working on, in between the two phrases that describe how you are doing it. I would have put that first. Thus, I would have written, "We must be capable of working on a project with people of different cultures without having any conflicts." But that wasn't the point of your question so I won't pursue that any further.